# How do I end program with user input in java?

Tags: java

I am currently having trouble to end my program with a users input. I currently now can only end when the user has inputted 20 numbers for example. What I want it to do is if a user inputs a number over 100, it should stop the program and display a histogram as well as a number to show the amount of times the user has inputted a number every time. Sorry if I am not making any sense, I will update this post if any further information is needed. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Marks {
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] array = new int[23];
        int num = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println ("Enter students marks in the range 0 to 100\n");

        for (count = 0; count <= 20; count++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter a number:");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            while (num < 0 || num > 100)
            {
                System.out.println ("Invalid number. Enter a valid number.");
                num = scan.nextInt();
            }
            array[count] = num;
           total=count;
        }
        System.out.println ("How many times a number between 0-100 occur.");

        String[] asterisk = {"0- 29   | ", "30- 39  | ","40- 69  | ", "70- 100 | "}; //4 strings

        for (count = 0; count <= 20; count++)
        {
            num=array[count];
            if (num <=29) asterisk [0] +="*";
            else if (num <=39) asterisk[1] +="*";
            else if (num <=69) asterisk[2] +="*";
            else if (num <=100) asterisk[3] +="*";
        }
        for (count =0;count < 4;count++)
            System.out.println(asterisk[count]);
        System.out.println("The total amount of students is " + total);
    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer. It should workl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have errors in your code**

Here is your updated code

```
public class Marks {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] array = new int[23];
    int num = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int total = 1;

    System.out.println ("Enter students marks in the range 0 to 100\n");

        loop: for (count = 0; count <= 20; count++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            if (num < 0 || num > 100) {
                break loop;

            }
            array[count] = num;
            total = count+1;
        }
    System.out.println ("How many times a number between 0-100 occur.");

    String[] asterisk = {"0- 29   | ", "30- 39  | ","40- 69  | ", "70- 100 | "}; //4 strings

    for (count = 1; count <= total; count++)
    {
        num=array[count];
        if (num >=0 && num<=29) asterisk [0] +="*";
        else if (num>29 && num<=39) asterisk[1] +="*";
        else if (num>39 && num <=69) asterisk[2] +="*";
        else if (num >69 && num <=100) asterisk[3] +="*";
    }
    for (count =0;count < 4;count++)
        System.out.println(asterisk[count]);
    System.out.println("The total amount of students is " + total);
}
}
```

**Here is the output**

```
Enter students marks in the range 0 to 100

Enter a number:
1

Enter a number:
10
Enter a number:
50
Enter a number:
111
How many times a number between 0-100 occur.
0- 29   | **
30- 39  | 
40- 69  | *
70- 100 | 
The total amount of students is 3
```

Comment: It worked but on my histogram it shows too many *'s when I only entered three numbers. It should only display three numbers in whichever range

Comment: Yes that's the problem it should not be doing that. You entered four numbers. Numbers 44, 44 and 55 should be displayed in range 40-69. The total amount of students should also be saying 3 not 2 since you entered 3 numbers that fall with the mark range. There should not be anything shown in 0-29 since there's no number that fits into that range.

Comment: Ah! Thank you it worked. It never came to my mind that I should have changed 20 to total. Didn't know it would work and neither it came to mind.

Comment: Not only that you should see hwo I have updated the if conditions. Thumb up and accept as answer now :)

Answer (score 4):

When the users interacts, you can write

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't show the histogram as well as doesn't let me enter more than 1 number

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (num >100) System.exit(0);
```

this should do the trick no ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using System.exit(0)?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout how to use while loops.

Instead of the for loop. and have some statment like

```
while( userinput < 100)
{
 //insert code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the matching condition  u can use System.exit(0)

```
if(matchCondition) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes... Quick and dirty:

```
    for (count = 0; count <= 20; count++)
    {
        System.out.println ("Enter a number:");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        while (num < 0 || num > 100)
        {
            if (num > 100) {
               count = 20;
               break;
            }

            System.out.println ("Invalid number. Enter a valid number.");
            num = scan.nextInt();

        }
        array[count] = num;
       total=count;
    }
```

But I wouldn't recommend this approach. Consider using while loop instead.